# Font Matching and Know-how?

Tags: fonts

I wanted to use Museo Slab font for my project. 
Can anyone tell me how to download this font for both web and desktop from cart?? and also any other similar font like museo slab which I can download for free?

Comment: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/museo-slab/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "shopping list' question which are just poor form for Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Scott: first of all thanks for the link. But it's coming as same link whihc I am opening but it's again paid??? and how to proceed in it further???

Comment: and yes regarding closing of this question -  Is this a forum not for helping people???? I don't know how this question is off-topic??? I have asked it for help in my graphic design work only?????

Comment: If you know any other means where I can ask this question. let me know pls.

Comment: I don't understand.... to proceed you add the font to your cart and pay for it. After payment you will be provided with a download link.  If you don't want to pay for it, I can't help you. It is a commercial font which *requires* payment. Stack Exchange isn't going to support anyone providing information on acquiring the font illegally.

Comment: Ya I was simply asking this only that is it really a paid font or is it avaliable as free download also, if I missed anything in searching for it. further I asked that if its a paid font then what is the process of buying a font. There is no point of illegacy in this friend :)

Comment: I wasn't making any accusations. Most commercial fonts require payment. If they require payment at one place, they'll require payment everywhere. If you find someplace which, unlike others, is giving it away free -- chances are *that* "free" file is illegal or not the actual font you are seeking.

Comment: and this isnt a "forum"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Museo Slab has 2 styles that are available for free, [Museo Slab 500 and Museo Slab 500 Italic](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Museo-Slab).
The rest are distributed under a [commercial licence](http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/exljbris/museo-slab?refby=pixilate), which means you have to pay in order to download it.

It seems to be priced consistently everywhere, $99 for the whole family or $16.50 for each individual style.

If you're on a tight budget, you might get away with using only the free styles, or complementing with one of two paid styles, but you're not going to get the family any cheaper, at least not legally.

Comment: Hi Spiral. Thanks alot for the info. Appreciate it :)